# MySQL table size

Tags: mysql

If I had a table with 500 million rows and good indexing would the DB suffer any performance degredation? I am wondering if I need to shard table over multiple DBs even if they might be on the same server. Each row might be 1k in size as it has a couple of text fields. Even if I foreign keyed them they would still be 500 million row table that comprises of say 700 bytes of data.

Also, any tips on engine selection for tables of this size would be great. 
Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Rich

Comment: Please tell us more information about the use you are planning for the table (ex. is read or write intensive), the kind of query you'll use etc.

Comment: The data is denormalised so there are no joins. I currently have it so that anything that is written to the DB is cached in memcache so I guess you could say the table will be write intensive rather than read as read is always out of cache. There will of course be a cache prime hit once a cache server is restarted. We will only cache on write and read if not in cache. i.e. if not cache.get(var) select x from y, save to cache and insert x, write to cache

Comment: I alswo wonder if my cached data is an unnecessary overhead as MySQL caches frequent read data anyway. How does one decide large memcache vs large memory allocation to mysql?

Comment: if it weren't for the cache i would say the read / write ratio would be 50 reads to 1 write

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports [user-defined partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) for large tables.

As for whether or not you need it, it depends on your application and what queries you make. Have a look at the advantages of partitioning and see if any of them apply to your situation:

> - Partitioning makes it possible to store more data in one table than can be held on a single disk or file system partition.
> - Data that loses its usefulness can often be easily removed from a partitioned table by dropping the partition (or partitions) containing only that data. Conversely, the process of adding new data can in some cases be greatly facilitated by adding one or more new partitions for storing specifically that data.
> - Some queries can be greatly optimized in virtue of the fact that data satisfying a given WHERE clause can be stored only on one or more partitions, which automatically excluding any remaining partitions from the search. Because partitions can be altered after a partitioned table has been created, you can reorganize your data to enhance frequent queries that may not have been often used when the partitioning scheme was first set up. This ability to exclude non-matching partitions (and thus any rows they contain) is often referred to as partition pruning, and was implemented in MySQL 5.1.6. For more information, see Section 18.4, “Partition Pruning”.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that having over 10 million records in an InnoDB table can be very slow when the table is joined, even with proper indices. Of you're just selecting from this table alone, without joins, grouping or sorting, it might just work.